# VBA delete spaces within a string

Tags: vba, excel, search, replace

I want to be able to delete all of the spaces from a group of cells so that the cell contents result in just being a string of information that I want. I have come up with a code but it doesn't work and I can't figure out whether I have to use a replace function or not

My code is:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim SearchString As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRowSource As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

SearchString = " " 'look for strings containing ( )

With ws1

    LastRowSource = .Cells.Find(" ", [B2], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRowSource)

            If InStr(cell.Value, SearchString) > 0 Then
                cell.Value = Replace(" ", "")
         End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA, just use Find and Replace from the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop:

```
With ws1
    .Range("B2", .Cells(.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)).Replace " ", vbnullstring, xlpart
End With
```

Comment: how do i specify this to work on the whole worksheet? @Rory

Comment: Just: `ws1.Cells.Replace " ", vbnullstring, xlpart`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this programmatically then, recording a Macro using the Replace dialog generates this code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Substitute your range for `Selection`. You do not need to iterate each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

`LastRowSource = 10000.`
If it works, then the problem is the way you are setting the last row. Thus, add the `LastRow()` function to your code, it should work:

```
LastRowSource = LastRow ws1

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Function from here - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm